# I need this loop to allow 3 people to enter information then print out the info with lists

Tags: python

```
    #identify the variables

floor_number = 0
rent_cost = 0
total_floors = 0
Floors = []
Rent = []
Names = []
a = 0

#begin while loop for user information

while ( a < 2):
    name1 = input("Please enter your name: ")
    Names.append(name1)
    floor_number = input("Please enter your floor number: ")
    Floors.append(floor_number)
    floor_number += (str(total_floors))

    if (floor_number >= 1):
        print("Your rent is: $1200")
        rent_cost = "$1200"
     
    elif (floor_number > 3):
        print("Your rent is: $1500")
        rent_cost = "$1500"

    elif(floor_number > 6):
        print("Your rent is: $2000")
        rent_cost = "$2000"

    elif(floor_number > 9):
        print("Your rent is: $3500")
        rent_cost = "$3500"

        Rent.append(rent_cost)
        a += 1
#end while loop of user information

#begin while loop to print out user information

i = 0
while( i < len(Names)):
    print(Names[a], "-----", Rent[a])
    i += 1

#print out the average floor and highest floor that were entered in the program

print("The average floor is: ", total_floors/3)
print("The highest floor is: ", max(Floors))
```

The question is phrased as follows:

An apartment complex charges monthly rental fees based on the floor of the apartment.  Write a python program that uses a loop to prompt for 3 customer names and the floor of their apartment.  Use the apartment floor to determine the monthly rent for each customer using the table below.  Your program should also determine the highest floor of the 3 customers and average floor for the 3 customers.  The program should display each customer name & monthly rent.  Also output the average floor of the 3 and highest floor of the 3.  Write the Python code to display the Test Data results

```
Floor

Monthly Rent

1 to 3

$1200

4 to 6

$ 1500

7 to 9

$2000

10

$3500

 TEST EXAMPLES OF CODE

Customer Name

Floor

Katia

5

Omar

2

Dominic

10
```

Comment: Generally speaking if you find yourself including the entire question that you are trying to solve in your stack overflow question, you're being too broad.

Comment: Im sorry, I just put it as a reference to my task. The loop keeps going forever and I can't get any output to work.

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. [edit] your question to include a [mcve] when it's some specific code that doesn't work as intended. Also remove the "PYTHON" from the title, that's what tags are for.

Comment: There are some things to fix on your code. As first suggestion I would recommend to check where you need numbers (int) and where you need strings (str). Advice: `input` function returns a string (str) as output, not a number (int).

Comment: Stefano, where would I need to place the "str" and "int"? I'm very new to python and unfamilar.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with the code, the main one being that floor number is a string and can not be compared to an integer.  That's why your while loop never ends. In the following code, instead of having multiple lists, I have a single dictionary to keep track of the data.  The dictionary key is the tenant name and the value is a list.  The first item in the list is the floor number and the second item is the monthly rent for that tenant.  At the end, you iterate through this dictionary to print the appropriate output.

```
dic = {} #key is name. Value is a list containing floor and rent.
a = 0
while (a < 3):
    name = input("Please enter your name: ")
    try: #make sure the user inputs a number
        floor_number = int(input("Please enter your floor number between 1 and 10: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input.")

    if 1 <= floor_number <= 10:
        a += 1
        dic[name] = [floor_number]
        if 1 <= floor_number <= 3:
            dic[name].append(1200)
        elif 4 <= floor_number <= 6:
            dic[name].append(1500)
        elif 7 <= floor_number <= 9:
            dic[name].append(2000)
        else:
            dic[name].append(3500)
    else: #make sure it's a valid floor. Otherwise don't count that input and prompt user again.
        print('No such floor. Try again.')

#loop through dictionary to print output
floors = []
for name, value_list in dic.items():
    print(f'{name} lives on floor {value_list[0]} and pays ${value_list[1]} in monthly rent.')
    floors.append(value_list[0])

#calculate and print aggregate data
highest_floor = max(floors)
average_floor = int(sum(floors)/len(floors))
print(f'The highest floor is floor {highest_floor}. The average floor is {average_floor}')
```

Sample output:

```
Please enter your name: Katia
Please enter your floor number between 1 and 10: 5
Please enter your name: Omar
Please enter your floor number between 1 and 10: 2
Please enter your name: Dominic
Please enter your floor number between 1 and 10: 10

Katia lives on floor 5 and pays $1500 in monthly rent.
Omar lives on floor 2 and pays $1200 in monthly rent.
Dominic lives on floor 10 and pays $3500 in monthly rent.
The highest floor is floor 10. The average floor is 5
```